# Multiplying respective cell values from two different raster layers

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

I am very new to GIS, I have two raster layers and a shapefile. I need to:

Multiply the respective cell values of both raster layers and then store final value into a new raster. So, I found a function called overlay and used this code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open("CEC_sd3_M_02_apr_2014_bbclip.tif")
ds1 = gdal.Open("BLD_sd3_M_02_apr_2014_bbclip.tif")
zeroRaster <- overlay(ds,ds1 fun=function(x,y){return (x*y*300000)})
```

But I end up getting syntax error, I know there is something wrong with this, but was not able to figure it out
Error Message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/lenovo/appdata/local/temp/tmp9tzawc.py", line 7
    zeroRaster <- overlay(ds,ds1 fun=function(x,y),{return(x*y*300000)})
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
execfile(u'c:/users/lenovo/appdata/local/temp/tmpng20xy.py'.encode('mbcs'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/lenovo/appdata/local/temp/tmpng20xy.py", line 7
    zeroRaster <- overlay(ds,ds1 fun=function(x,y){return (x*y*300000)})
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). In it, you'll see that there should be only one question per Question, and that you need to include what you have attempted to solve your problem. Please attempt to accomplish your task list, then edit this question to specify the problem if you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: What was the precise and full error message that you received from running the code that you have presented?

Comment: You are using `R` syntax (e.g. `zeroRaster <-`) in a `Python` script - therefore Python throws a syntax error. Your shapefile is also never opened - what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: Yes, I've figured it out. Thanks a lot for your effort. rasterCalculator is the function that does my work.
As I've said, I intended to multiply pixel values of two individual rasters and store the corresponding result in a new raster